# App with Azure Mobile Service - Custom + FB Login

Tags: cordova, azure, authentication, facebook-login, azure-mobile-services

I have a general question regarding the architecture and flow for a login in a mobile app with azure.

So far i created a custom login with an account table (id, username...). 
But i also want to allow the user to login with his facebook account. Azur already provides a login over facebook but how can i combine the facebook login with the account table?

Another thing that i am thinking about is: It is a cordova app and there is already a facebook plugin for cordova. Should i forget about it because of the azure mobile service.
After the user logged in over facebook i also want to use the facebook api, i guess for that i need the cordova plugin. So maybe it is a good idea to use the cordova plugin login and send the login info to my azur custom login service to store the info to the account table?
Any other suggestions?

Maybe somene can help me or knows another resource where this problem has already been discussed? (so far i didn't find anything)

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here. You should limit each question to a single topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Azure Mobile Services you want to separate the concept of an auth from a user.

In general a user authenticates using Facebook, Twitter or email/username (more on that later) and then you get back a token and an azure user id. You then use that azure user id as a unique key in your user table where you store all the needed info for that user.

Facebook and Twitter are built in. You use the SDK and it will give you back the unique id you need to register a user or look up a user.

If you want to allow login via Email/Username + password you need to build the auth endpoint on the server side and return the exact same token and azure user id as the built-in methods return.

It is pretty well documented [here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Generating_your_own_ZUMO_auth_token_Day_8_.aspx) and [here](http://chrisrisner.com/Authentication-with-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services) for Node backend and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/) for C#.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already implemented the Email/Username + password login for my C# backend. So you mean that in the case that i use facebook, twitter...: i should take the unique key that i get from the sdk and save that to the usertable that i use for my own custom login?

The concrete steps for a login would be:
1. Login over SKD (thats were the mobile service authentication happens)
2. Response contains userID
3. Call "saveUserEndpoint" with that userID
4. Work with that generated userentry

Comment: You got it. Although I would say it is 1. Authenticate over SDK. 2. Response contains userId. 3. Check if this user exists in your user table (based on azure user id). 4. If user exists, load the user and login complete. 5. If no user exists, take them to the registration screen and then save the auth info with the registration info.